# Communicating with SRF02 Ranging sensor on Linu

Tags: debian, usb, serial-port, sensors, ttyusb

I have an SRF02 Ultra sonic range finder, connected to my Debian 8 laptop via a USB-I2C communications module. My problem is that I cannot get any data back from the device. (I know the device works because I can access it on windows).

The USB-I2C documentation says you must send bytes directly to the device and gives info on how to do this. Below is the order of the bytes:

- 1) I2C_AD1 Command
- 2) Device i2c address
- 3) Device internal register
  address
- 4) Number of bytes we are reading

The following string of bytes should output the software version:

```
0x55 0xE1 0x00 0x01
```

To do this, I run these two commands:

```
$ printf '\x55\xE1\x00\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0
$ hexdump -n 1 -e '"%02x \n"' < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

printf appears to work but **I don't get any output from hexdump**, it hangs until I kill the command.

How should I go about trouble shooting this?

`$tty` returns `/dev/pts/0`
The ttyUSB0 is created and setup with no errors when the device is plugged in.
I have disconnected the mode plug, ensuring the SRF02 is in i2c mode.

USB-I2C docs: http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/usb_i2c_tech.htm
SRF02 docs: https://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf02techI2C.htm

Thanks in advance!!
Max